# Map does not show up

Tags: 8, blocks, google-maps

I am creating a new custom block; when I put HTML into the body and select *Full HTML* as text format, it gives me only the source code back. What might be the problem? This is a full HTML link I get from http://maps-website.com/.

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key= AIzaSyADwz5L6rGV82W_Iom2uMxbyP_mR2ZPEVw '></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:425px;width:1920px;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:425px;width:1920px;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <a href='https://embedmaps.net'>embed a google map</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=ac49ccff700b1b72264816987089dabdd343ea85'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:12,center:new google.maps.LatLng(55.68811213574507,12.744411111718822),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(55.68811213574507,12.744411111718822)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Vento Maritime</strong><br>Toldbodgade 35<br> Copenhagen<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);</script>
```

EDIT: While looking at developer's tools console, I noticed there is 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Are you able to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before paste the code you need to click on "Source" option.

See the screen shot

[image]

Comment: thank you for an offer, but I tried it, sadly it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Check this https://rgog1.ply.st/

Answer (score 0):

[image]use Markup module which helps with custom html maps.. if it doesnt work ping me up... I will provide you the code...See the image below for limitations...